# what would be the best input shape in cnn?

Tags: image, image-processing, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

When i have high resolution image. (512,512,3) or (150,150,3) which input shape outperform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general it depends on what you want to achieve and how you define "outperform".

(512, 512, 3) will lead to better performance on some kind of metric like. accuracy, IoU ... (depending on the task), (150, 150, 3) will lead to worse performance but better runtime and less memory consumption.